# Pyspark window lead function with offset value from value of different column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rolling-computation

I am trying to derive a new column using window lead function, but my offset value to lead function varies depending on the value of the column, here is my example data

```
inputdata = (("James", "Sales", 3000), \
    ("James", "Sales", 4600),  \
    ("James", "Sales", 4100),   \
    ("James", "Finance", 3000),  \
    ("James", "Sales", 3000),    \
    ("James", "Finance", 3300),  \
    ("James", "Finance", 3900),    \
    ("Kumar", "Marketing", 3000), \
    ("Kumar", "Marketing", 2000),\
    ("James", "Sales", 4100) \
  )
  
columns= ["employee_name", "department", "salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = inputdata, schema = columns)
```

**input**

```
+-------------+----------+------+
|employee_name|department|salary|
+-------------+----------+------+
|James        |Sales     |3000  |
|James        |Sales     |3000  |
|James        |Sales     |4100  |
|James        |Sales     |4100  |
|James        |Sales     |4600  |
|James        |Finance   |3000  |
|James        |Finance   |3300  |
|James        |Finance   |3900  |
|Kumar        |Marketing |2000  |
|Kumar        |Marketing |3000  |
+-------------+----------+------+
```

**expected output:**

Here I have a column called **expected value**

it needs to be derived from salary column, and the value needs to be **next immediate big value**

if the next value of the column is same then it should consider next value until it finds the different value,

in below example expected value for first two columns is 4100 which is next big value here 9999 is the default value

[image]

I have used window lead function but the problem is offset needs to be constant I mean lead can go forward only till fixed number of records, is there any way to solve this ?

this is what I have tried:

created an offset column that,  lead function needs to go far

```
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("employee_name","department","salary").orderBy('employee_name','department','salary')
dfk = df.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec))
dfk = dfk.withColumn("max_row_number", max(col("row_number")+1).over(windowSpec))
dfk = dfk.orderBy("employee_name","department","salary").withColumn('offset', dfk['max_row_number']-dfk['row_number'])

+-------------+----------+------+----------+--------------+------+
|employee_name|department|salary|row_number|max_row_number|offset|
+-------------+----------+------+----------+--------------+------+
|        James|   Finance|  3000|         1|             2|     1|
|        James|   Finance|  3300|         2|             3|     1|
|        James|   Finance|  3900|         3|             4|     1|
|        James|     Sales|  3000|         1|             3|     2|
|        James|     Sales|  3000|         2|             3|     1|
|        James|     Sales|  4100|         3|             5|     2|
|        James|     Sales|  4100|         4|             5|     1|
|        James|     Sales|  4600|         5|             6|     1|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  2000|         1|             2|     1|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  3000|         2|             3|     1|
+-------------+----------+------+----------+--------------+------+
```

but I am not able to pass offset column as offset to lead function or something like this

```
windowSpec_2  = Window.partitionBy("employee_name","department").orderBy('employee_name','department','salary','row_number')
dfk.withColumn("*** expected value ****",lead('salary', **dfk['offset']**, 9999).over(windowSpec_2)).show()
```

I have tried using express/eval but I still see the

> **iter**
> raise TypeError("Column is not iterable") TypeError: Column is not iterable

is there any way to achieve the above expected results ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is a bit tricky, so I think `lead` may not be appropriate. You may be better off using a `rangeBetweeen` window, and get the `min` value in that window:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'expected_value',
    F.coalesce(
        F.min('salary').over(
            Window.partitionBy(
                "employee_name","department"
            ).orderBy(
                'salary'
            ).rangeBetween(
                1, Window.unboundedFollowing
            )
        ),
        F.lit(9999)
    )
)

df2.show()
+-------------+----------+------+--------------+
|employee_name|department|salary|expected_value|
+-------------+----------+------+--------------+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|          4100|
|        James|     Sales|  3000|          4100|
|        James|     Sales|  4100|          4600|
|        James|     Sales|  4100|          4600|
|        James|     Sales|  4600|          9999|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  2000|          3000|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  3000|          9999|
|        James|   Finance|  3000|          3300|
|        James|   Finance|  3300|          3900|
|        James|   Finance|  3900|          9999|
+-------------+----------+------+--------------+
```